# Filter data from api calls in Next.js in SSG to increase performance

Tags: next.js

I vaguely remember seeing an NPM module that does this, but can't find it - is there a better way than just destructing off the api in SSG (next.js).

Use Case:

- If the API is huge, many times we just pass that data INTO the "getStaticProps" not realizing this could be a performance hit if we need only a few fields and we pass in this giant payload.

Solution:

- Just destructor what I need off of the api.

The solution is fine, but I remember seeing an npm that does this and sorta gives a graphql vibe and allows for nested objects/arrays etc..

What are your strategies for this?

Comment: I think your solution is reasonable. From my understanding, SSG is cacheable and it only happens in build-time. That means clients won't have any performance impact. If you concern about a huge API response, that would be a back-end solution to break that response into small data pieces.

Comment: Well, there 'would' be a perfomance impact on the client when they request that page because those props passed in have to get saved to a json file right? And if that json file is HUGE, it would impact it even though its "pre-built". It still has to be downloaded by the user ,no?